# Change certain values in column to certain other values in SQL with one UPDATE command

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to change value1 to value2 and value3 to value4 with one UPDATE command.

Here is something I have tried to give a better look:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = value1, column = value3
WHERE column = value2, column = value4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case expression:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = CASE mycolumn WHEN 'value1' THEN 'value2'
                                WHEN 'value3' THEN 'value4'
                  END
WHERE  mycolumn IN ('value1', 'value3')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    column = CASE column WHEN 'value2' THEN 'value1'
                         WHEN 'value4' THEN 'value3' END
WHERE
    column IN ('value2', 'value4');
```